# How to resolve this issue with top-level const?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, constants

I have a class template that contains two similar member functions:

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate {
   // other stuff, then
   static T* member( T& ); //line 100
   static const T* member( const T& ); //line 101
```

};

which I instantiate like this:

```
MyTemplate<int* const>
```

and Visual C++ 9 complains:

```
mytemplate.h(101) : error C2535: 'int* MyTemplate<T>::member(T &)' :
   member function already defined or declared
with
[
    T=int *const 
]
mytemplate.h(100) : see declaration of 'MyTemplate::member'
with
[
    T=int *const 
]
somefile.cpp(line) : see reference to class template instantiation
    'MyTemplate<T>' being compiled
with
[
    T=int *const 
]
```

I certainly need the two versions of `member()` - one for const reference and one for non-const reference. I guess the problem has something with top-level const qualifiers, but can't deduce how to solve it.

How do I resolve this problem so that I still have two versions of `member()` and the template compiles?

Answer (score 2):

When `T` is `int * const`, `T` is already `const`, so `T&` and `const T&` are both `int * const`.

Or do you mean in this case, you need your class to look like:

```
class MyTemplate_int_p_const{
     static int * member (int *&);
     static int * const member (int * const &);
};
```

You can add this to your main template to achieve this:

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate<const T>
{
    static T * member(T&);
    static const T* member(const T&);
};
```

As a responds to the OP's comment, if you don't want to use partial specialization, you'll need type_traits. It is supported by C++0x, and for VC++9, you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).

In the following code, the non_const version of `member` will take a `dummy_type` ( a pointer to member function) if `T` is already const. So the non_const overload would not exist.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
class MyTemplate {
   // other stuff, then

   //void dummy(void);
   typedef void (*dummy_type)(void);
   typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, dummy_type, T>::type T_no_const;
   typedef typename std::remove_const<T>::type T_remove_const;
   static T_no_const* member( T_no_const& t ) //line 100
   {
       if (std::is_same<T, T_no_const>::value)
       {
           return member_portal(t);
       }
       else
           return NULL;
   }
   static T_no_const* member_portal(dummy_type&){return NULL;};
   static T_remove_const* member_portal(T_remove_const&);
   static const T* member( const T& ); //line 101

};


int main()
{
    MyTemplate<int * const> mt;
    MyTemplate<int *> mtt;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the first time that I play with `type_traits`. It can pass compilation under g++ 4.5.2 with C++0x enabled. But I've never run it.

Main idea is, when `T` is const, the non_const version of member takes a argument of an arbitrary type ( a type that is not likely to be used any where else, and to not likely to be implicitly converted to), thus the non_const version disappears. But in the way, the logic breaks in the implementation of `member` ( as the argument type is to be used, but is not expected).  So the main logic of `member` is move another function of `member_portal`.

Comment: I'd rather prefer to have only const version when `T` is const. Is that possible?

Comment: @sharptooth Of course, remove the non-const version of `member` in the partial specialization.

Comment: My template is actually about one hundred members - the partial specialization idea doesn't sound cool.

Comment: @sharptooth In that case, you'd need to play with type_traits. It is supported by c++0x. I think you can find boost equivalent in VC++9.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation given by fefe is correct. `Foo const&` and `Foo const const&` will simply evaluate to the same type, hence your function overloading does not work. In case your template argument is const, I'd suggest specialisation.

Version A:

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate {
   static T* member( T& );
   static const T* member( const T& );
};
template<class T>
class MyTemplate<T const> {
   static const T* member( const T& );
};
```

Version B:

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate_mutableImpl {
   static T* member( T& );
};
template<class T>
class MyTemplate_constImpl {
   static const T* member( const T& );
};
template<class T>
class MyTemplate : public MyTemplate_mutableImpl<T>, public MyTemplate_constImpl<T> {
};
template<class T>
class MyTemplate<T const> : public MyTemplate_constImpl<T const> {
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to disable the function if `T` is `const`:

```
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp>

template<class T>
class MyTemplate {
   static T* member( T& );
   struct Disabled {};
   static const T* member(typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_const<T>, Disabled, const T&>::type);
};
```